# How to assert on a list of element attributes with Cypress

Tags: cypress

Using Cypress, I want to iterate over a bunch of rows that all have a specific element that has an attribute and then match for each attribute value. Each attribute has a fill color of red, green or orange. I inherited a test that started out the following way:

```
  it('Should correctly render urgency indicators', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy="table"] tr [data-cy=urgency-indicator]')
      .should('have.length', 13)
      .as('urgency-indicators');

    cy.get('@urgency-indicators').then(($indicators) => {
      const fills = $indicators.get().map((i) => i.getAttribute('fill'));
      expect(fills).to.deep.equal([...
```

I want to refactor to use Cypress commands instead of Javascript commands for my own learning and because it's in a spec file so I want to use Cypress when possible. I refactored down to this:

```
  it.only('Should render urgency indicators', () => {
    cy.dataCy('urgency-indicator')
      .should('have.length', 13)
      .as('urgency-indicators');
    cy.get('@urgency-indicators').each(($match) => {
      cy.wrap($match).invoke('attr', 'fill');
```

but if I then add a `.should(contain)`, I'm not sure how to proceed. I can assert that `.should(contain, '#EA1616')` matches the first element with the correct color, then fails on the third dot because it is a different color and I still need to iterate on the remaining element attributes.

If I print out `console.log('match: ', $match[0].attributes[3]);` I can see the color attribute of each row

I tried looking for solutions that would match one of the four colors and then pass if any of them exist, but I do not see how they work with element attributes instead of elements. It looks like contains does not work with OR values.

I also tried using index values but I'm not sure how to do this either. i.e. I could match on `element[0] = #EA1616`, `element[1] = F9C87B`

Does anyone have a good solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would want to make use of the index parameter, and use it to pick from an expected array of colors, like so

```js
const colors = [...]

cy.get('@urgency-indicators').each(($match, index) => {
  cy.wrap($match)
    .invoke('attr', 'fill')
    .should('eq', colors[index])
```